# Laravel 5.0 how to order an eloquent with() query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models: item and faq.  The are in a belongsToMany with each other with a correctly created join table: item_faq (singular of both).  My join table has an additional field on it for order.

In my view I get all the faq's and if they have a pivot table record I output "checked" on a checkbox.  I also have drag and drop ordering on the checkbox list and that works well.

A few code notes:

```
// ITEMS MODEL
public function faqs(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Faq');
    }

// FAQ MODEL
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item');
}

public function hasItem($item) {
    $items = $this->items->lists('id');
    return in_array($item, $items);
}
```

Schema of join table:

- item_id
- faq_id
- order
- timestamps

My issue is that they faq's don't load sorted by the order column on the pivot table.

I am using a very simple:

```
$faqs = \App\Faq::with('items')->get();
```

To retrieve the FAQ's and this works at getting all the faq's and if they are related, it checks the checkbox.

How can I order these by the order column on the join table?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Eager Load Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) and I *think* it will help provide a solution. From the docs:

> Of course, eager loading Closures aren't limited to "constraints". You may also apply orders:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query) {

    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

}])->get();
```

Comment: I have tried that but the order of the items doesn't change.  If the orderBy field isn't found does the order revert to some kind of default?  Should I be referencing the item_faq.order or just order?

Comment: Looking at your provided `FAQ model`, I don't see the `items` relationship defined. Is it there and just not provided above? As for the default behavior, I believe it sorts by `id`. I don't suspect adding `item_faq.order` will change since the closure is tied to the `items` join.

Comment: My apologies I had mislabelled some of that code. The Items relationship is defined above (now).   Basically the orderBy doesn't seem to be affecting the order which I don't understand.

Comment: Hmm. It _should_ work (I've just tested it here and I can get it to reverse when changing the second argument in the closure). Just to confirm: it does work otherwise, right? As in the relationship is defined properly and the only issue is the order of the `with` data?

Comment: It seems that the only issue is the <code>with</code> data.

Comment: Can you show the results of a faq with `dd($faq)`? Because if the relationship is defined properly, then this closure constraint should be working. Maybe a `dd()` will provide insight.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123965/discussion-between-tj-sherrill-and-camelcase).

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for the help.